# Ui is not updating from viewmodel kotlin flow

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel, kotlin-flow

I am quite new in Android Flow and JetPack compose,

I am trying to update my UI when mutable state is being changed , but this is not calling our composable , here is my code

```
    @Composable
    fun Grid() {
        val mainViewModel by viewModels<DashBoardViewModel>()
        mainViewModel.getData()
        when (val result = mainViewModel.mutableState.value) {
            is Resource.Success -> {
                LazyVerticalGrid(
                    cells = GridCells.Adaptive(100.dp)
                ) {
                    items(result.device.items.first().devices.count()) {
                        EachItem(it)
                    }
                }
            }
            is Resource.Error -> { Text(text = result.message) }
            Resource.Loading -> { CircularProgressIndicator() }
            Resource.Empty -> {}
            else -> { CircularProgressIndicator() }
        }
    }
```

ViewModel:

```
@HiltViewModel
class DashBoardViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val dashBoardRepository: DashBoardRepository
) : ViewModel() {

   
    val mutableState = MutableLiveData<Resource>()

    fun getData() = viewModelScope.launch {

        flow {
            emit(Resource.Loading)
            try {
               val mResponse = dashBoardRepository.getDevice()
                emit(Resource.Success(mResponse))
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
                emit(Resource.Error("Error"))
            }
        }.flowOn(Dispatchers.IO).collect {
            mutableState.value = it
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems in your code:

- `mainViewModel.mutableState.value` gets only the current value from your mutable state. Your composable will not be notified when this value changes and thus it cannot reflect the change. If you want to use `LiveData` in your viewmodel, you have to use `observeAsState()` [extension function](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/livedata/package-summary) which converts `LivaData` to `State` that can be automatically observed by composable function. Other option is to have `(Mutable)State` directly in your viewmodel. See [this](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state) state explanation.
- Your `mainViewModel.getData()` function will be called every time your `Grid()` function recomposes, which will be every time your `mainViewModel.mutableState` changes (once you observe it correctly). You definitely don't want that. Better solution would be to call `getData()` from your viewModel's `init` block, or, if you really need to call it from your composable function, use [LaunchedEffect](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects#launchedeffect).

And, as a side note, the way you are creating flow and then collecting it into `LiveData` is really odd and unnecessary. You can do something like this instead:

```
fun getData() = viewModelScope.launch {
    mutableState.value = Resource.Loading
    try {
        val mResponse = dashBoardRepository.getDevice()
        mutableState.value = Resource.Success(mResponse)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        mutableState.value = Resource.Error("Error")
    }
}
```